# If I add @Size(min>2) does it make sense to also use @NotNull annotation?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, annotations

I m working on a school project which involves working with a database and JPA and I m wondering if I should keep the annotation @NotNull where I already have the annotation @Size(min>2&& max<10). I mean having a String of at least 2 characters also means that String is not Null or I m wrong?

Let's say for example for the column Username

```
@Column
@NotNull
@Size(min = 2,max = 10)
private String username;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between string as null or string as empty.

```
 String s; or String s=null;
```

here string is null so no method can be invoked using it, 
If you try to do so it'll give NPE, therefore you should use @NotNull

```
String s ="";
```

here string is empty and has length as 0, so it will fail your condition given in @Size

Hope it helps !!

Comment: I understand what is a null String, but my problem is if I'm using @Size(min>N) where N is any number greater than 0, wouldn't the @NotNull annotation be useless?

Comment: No, because @NotNull is not looking for your length, its making sure that your variable is not null. Java will throw exceptions when this attribute is not set